# eval returns string instead of value

Tags: ruby

Can someone explain why eval is returning the string, rather than the result of the expression?

```
perms=["12+2","22","-2+"]
perms.each { |line|
matches=/^[\d]+[+-\/\*]{1}[\d]+$/.match(line)
s=matches.to_a
puts s
puts eval(s.to_s)
}
```

Comment: As an aside, in regular expressions `[\d]` is the same as `\d` and `[+-\/\*]{1}` is the same as `[+-\/*]`, so your expression can be simplified to `/^\d+[+-\/*]\d+/`.

Comment: You should avoid `eval`. Instead, you could use `/^(\d+)\+(\d+)$/` and calculate the result via `$1.to_i + $2.to_i`. Same for subtraction, multiplication and division.

Comment: @Stefan: if it's static data - why not?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that's a crucial "if". I just see little to no reason to use potentially dangerous methods when safer alternatives exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s = matches.to_a` is an array `["12+2"]`, the `eval(s.to_s)` will return the array `["12+2"]`, and when you print it, you will get the output `12+2`, a string representation of the array `["12+2"]`.

You should be `eval`ing the element of the array, in this case, `s[0]` or `s.first`.

Fix it like this:

```
perms=["12+2","22","-2+"]
perms.each do |line|
    matches=/^[\d]+[+-\/\*]{1}[\d]+$/.match(line)
    if matches
        s = matches.to_a
        puts eval(s.first)
    end
end
```

`matches` can be `nil` if there was no match.  Use `eval` only if its not `nil` by checking `if matches`

---

You could further simplify the code and write something like this:

```
perms=["12+2","22","-2+"]
perms.each do |line|
    puts eval(line) if line =~ /^[\d]+[+-\/\*]{1}[\d]+$/
end
```

Comment: Consider using `String#scan` instead of `match` to avoid check for `nil`. The former always returns an array, possibly empty.

Comment: Thanks for the simplified code, and the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating through inputs, one might directly map them to outputs:

```
perms.map do |p|                      # map inputs to outputs
  eval(p) if p =~ /\A\d+[+-\/*]\d+\z/ # return eval’ed or nil
end.compact                           # get rid of nils

#⇒ [14]
```